# Green Bar for Self-Made SSL

Tags: asp.net, linux, apache, ssl, certificate

So, considering the pricing for SSLs, I chose to try creating my own SSL certificate (still in the works).

Once I get that part done, how to I get the EV and green bar aspect of the certificate set up?

Comment: what about this:http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/free-ssl-certificate.html?gclid=CIiWtOjjvrACFUUhtAodtG1Aqw or even this http://www.godaddy.com/compare/gdcompare_ssl.aspx?isc=sslqeur47&currencytype=EUR&ef_id=NtRPWcyzPGcAAMUF%3a20120608134833%3as . but Paddy is right, because if everyone could do that how would anyone know if the certificate is save.

Comment: Note that a self-signed cert on the public internet will generate full-screen browser warnings for all of your visitors

Comment: Considering the pricing for SSL you have already exceeded the budget. You would be better off investigating other CAs. You will get a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can make sense to create your own certificates (and use your own CA) if you're in an environment where your users can import your own CA certificate in a way they can verify it independently. Typically, this works fine on an institution's network where someone installs the extra CA certificate as part of the OS configuration when configuring centrally-administered machines (and similar cases). Under these conditions, this will get you a blue bar without any problem.

Extended Validation certificate (which produce a green bar) rely on two things:

- Extra policy attributes in the certificate: technically, you could define some OIDs yourself, although getting others to recognise it will be a problem, obviously.
- [OID policies and root certificate fingerprints that are hard-coded in the browser](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14064/2435).

This second point is what will prevent you from doing it yourself. Non-EV certificates is something you could potentially implement on machines under your control using a few extra configuration steps. EV certificates also require that you control the compilation of the browser: this is not going to happen for proprietary browsers such as IE, and it can still be quite a lot of work for open-source browsers (e.g. Firefox/Chromium), since you wouldn't be able to rely on the pre-compiled binaries (and you'd have to recompile it yourself for every new release).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably going to find that all that nice stuff (assuming you are talking about the padlock and green bar in the browser) depends on the other part of certification, the fact that the certificate has been issued by a trusted provider who has verified your identity - this you probably can't do on your own.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of SSL certificates is that somebody everybody trusts (mozilla, microsoft) certify certifiers (thawte etc) to certify sites they audit (somehow) as being genuine. This wont work with your certificate, the idea is a trust chain. microsoft trusts thawte, they trust you. Nobody trusts you in your case so your self-signed certificate means nothing to browsers.